# Justify-content evenly spaced items in a flexbox not actually applying to the elements | ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

This is my mockup I made in Figma:
[image: Figma mockup]

This is what it looks like right now:
[image: what it looks like right now :(]

Here is my (S)CSS (react code) for the webpage layout:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-weight: normal;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: 0.1em;
}


*::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.mainContent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.cardLinks {
    display: inline-flex;
    gap: 120px;
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-top: 2em;
}

.userStats-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```

And here is the ReactJS Code (basically just HTML) for the layout:

```html
<div className="mainContent">
            <SNavbar />
            <div className="content">
                <Title
                    title="Hey, welcome back"
                    subtitle="Some quick actions for you:"
                    name="Henry Sargeant"
                />

                <div className="cardLinks">
                    <CardLink
                        text="Lookup a Pupil"
                        link="#"
                        svgAltText="Lookup Pupil Image"
                        svg="lookupPupilCard"
                    />
                    <CardLink
                        text="Manage Admins"
                        link="#"
                        svgAltText="Manage Admins Image"
                        svg="manageAdminsBlack"
                    />
                    <CardLink
                        text="Manage Users"
                        link="#"
                        svgAltText="Manage Users Image"
                        svg="manageUsersBlack"
                    />
                    <CardLink
                        text="Lookup a Pupil"
                        link="#"
                        svgAltText="Lookup a Pupil Image"
                        svg="lookupPupilsBlack"
                    />
                    <CardLink
                        text="View Error Logs"
                        link="#"
                        svgAltText="View Error Logs Image"
                        svg="warnBlack"
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="userStats-container">
                    <UserStats />
                    <CurrentAdmins admins={adminList} />
                    <StaffMembers staff={staff} />
                </div>

                <div className="switchstaffbtn">
                    <SwitchButton />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am trying to make it so that the 3 things in the userstats-container all are spaced away from each other horizontally equally.

I have tried flexbox and then `justify-content: space-between;` but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe because your container flex width is not full as the figma, inspect element the eidth of container to see width of your container or give background color red or something else.

Answer (score 1):

try align-content: space-between

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things you can try out..

1. Check if the parent container userStats-container has enough width to accommodate the spaces in between. (or give it a 100% width)
2. Check the widths of the children and make sure that it is fixed (ie. not stretched as per the container size)
3. By default flex-direction is row, so that can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing I can think of here is that to check the width using the inspector of the userstats-Container make sure it is occupying 100% width of the parent component i.e mainContent. Also, flex-direction is default set to row, so you don't need to write that extra property

```
    .userStats-container {
    display: flex;
    width:100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```